# How Can I Add Console Appender In Logger Object Using log4j-over-slf4j Dependency?

Tags: log4j, log4j2, logback, slf4j, slf4j-api

I can't be able to add console appender using logger.addAppender method with log4j-over-slf4j 1.7.x dependency. Moreover, I am unable to set target of that particular Console Appender(i.e., SYSTEM_OUT/SYSTEM_ERR).

I have initialized a console appender object and tried to push that reference into addAppender method by typecasting that reference to Appender. But in that case I am unable to set Target/WriterLocation(i.e., SYSTEM_OUT/SYSTEM_ERR) for console appender reference. I have used the below code snippet-

ConsoleAppender ca = new ConsoleAppender();
ca.setWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)); // this line is not compatible with log4j-over-slf4j jar
ca.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%-5p [%t]: %m%n"));
logger.addAppender(ca);

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing doesn't make a lot of sense. log4j-over-slf4j will route calls like logger.debug(), logger.info(), etc to slf4j and then presumably to some other logging framework to be logged. Your code is trying to manipulate log4j 1 objects which won't be involved in logging since you are routing log events to SLF4J (which is why many of them aren't supported by log4j-over-slf4j).

In order to help you we would know what logging implementation you really want to use.